# Script Eclipse to open a file in emacs

Tags: eclipse, emacs

Is it possible to script Eclipse so I can quickly open a source file that is open in Eclipse with emacs (or emacsclient)?

Comment: Tangentially, you might also be interested in https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Window Preferences then choose General/Editor/File Associations. Add "emacsclientw" to .*java file association. You will be able to use "Open With Emacsclient" from the Navigator or the Package Explorer.

Not so quick but better than nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like the file associations solution by Oleg because then eclipse will try to open the file in Emacs the next time you open it in the package explorer.

I setup a script that runs emacsclient as an external tool.

I use a script in ~/bin/openInEmacs.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
emacsclient --quiet --no-wait "$@"
wmctrl -a emacs
```

I do this because sometimes emacs doesn't come to the front with emacsclient from eclipse.

Go to external tools configuration. click the add icon. Name the new tool emacsclient.
set:
location to ~/bin/openInEmacs.sh,
Working directory to ${container_loc}
arguments to ${selected_resource_loc}

Under the common tab click display in favorites menu, check 'launch in background'. Uncheck the console and file outputs.

The to use this, select a file in the package explorer and click emacsclient under toolbar button for external tools.